# Dropdown Alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down in column header of the table. The Drop Down element is as shown below

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle grad1" >
    <b>Impact</b><span class="caret"></span><span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
</button>    
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="position:relative;top:inherit;left:inherit;cursor:pointer">
    <li><a ng-click="filterImpact('')">All</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="filterImpact('H')">High</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="filterImpact('M')">Medium</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="filterImpact('L')">Low</a></li>
  </ul>
```

But the drop down is not attached to the Main Menu. i.e If i scroll down than the drop down remains in the same location and doesn't move up along with the Header. The obvious solution is to make

```
position:relative
```

but in that case the options are hidden behind the table and not accessible to the user. I am missing some css over here.. 
please help :)

**UPDATE**

Things tried so  far.

```
     position:absolute,fixed,relative
```

and

```
     z-index:2000 //so it surpasses all elements.
```

**UPDATE**

To make things easier  [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TOhDhRYM74k3Qevb57wT?p=preview) is the plunk.
Select Gender Drop Down is not working here.

Comment: can you post your actual CSS code please

Comment: this is bootstrap drop down menu. so I am using its CDN. and hence I haven't included the css behind it. and regarding my custom css I haven't added anything except the style tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `display: inline;` to your style.

Comment: Sorry that makes the drop down fixed and without clicking the menu also it is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add z-index attribute to dropdown

Answer (score 0):

change position,top and margin and z-index to be on top.

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
margin-top:30px;
z-index:9999;
```

[Jsfiddle Sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Sanju_Bollera/7Jsde/)